# Realocar Tamanho de minha estrutura em C?

Tags: c, c++

```
typedef struct tempNo {

    int valor;
    int coluna;
    struct tempNo* prox; 

} NO;

typedef NO* PONT;

typedef struct {

    PONT* A;
    int linhas;
    int colunas;

} MATRIZ;

void inicializaMatriz(MATRIZ* m, int linnha, int coluna) {

    int i;

    m->linhas = linnha;
    m->colunas = coluna;
    m->A = (PONT*) malloc(linnha*sizeof(PONT));
    for (i = 0; i < linnha ; i++){
        m->A[i] = NULL;
    }   
}



int atribuirValor(MATRIZ* m, int lin, int col, int valor) {

    if (lin < 0 || lin >= m->linhas || col < 0 || col >= m->colunas ) return  1;

    PONT ant = NULL;
    PONT atual = m->A[lin];

    while(atual !=  NULL && atual->coluna < col ){

        ant = atual;
        atual = atual->prox;
    }

    if (atual != NULL && atual->coluna == col) {
        if (valor == 0) {
            if (ant == NULL) m->A[lin] = atual->prox;
            else ant->prox = atual->prox;
            free(atual);        
        }
        else  atual->valor = valor;  

    } else if (valor != 0){
        PONT novo = (PONT) malloc (sizeof(NO));
        novo->coluna = col;
        novo->valor = valor;
        novo->prox = atual;
        if (ant == NULL) m->A[lin] = novo;
        else ant->prox = novo;   
    }
    return 0; 

}


int acessarValor(MATRIZ* m, int lin , int col) {

    if (lin < 0 || lin >= m->linhas || col < 0 || col >= m->colunas ) return 0;

    PONT atual = m->A[lin];
    while (atual != NULL && atual->coluna < col )
        atual = atual->prox;
    if (atual != NULL && atual->coluna == col)
        return atual->valor; 
    return 0;

}

void anxexarColuna(MATRIZ* m){

    int i = m->colunas;
    i = i + 1;
    m->colunas = i;
}


void anexarLinha(MATRIZ* m){

    int i = m->linhas;
    i = i + 1;


}
```

Comment: Qual a estrutura que está a tentar realocar e onde no código exatamente ? Quando expõe o seu problema tente ser o mais especifico possível.

Comment: PONT* A : É uma lista de ponteiro para NO que aponta para o início de cada lista de NO. PONT* A, representa as colunas da  minha Matriz. Já NO são listas ligadas com ponteiros para para prox que representam  as linhas da minha Matriz. Eu quero alocar mais espaço para para PONT* A. pois como viu na função Anexar colunas para adicionar mais colunas eu preciso fazer isto, alocar mais espaço em PONT* A.

Comment: Em que função ? realocar para um array é feito com [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/)

Comment: Na função anexar coluna. Eu tentei usar o realloc porém não obtive sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apesar da sua dúvida não estar muito clara optei por responder na mesma, até para tentar ajudar em alguns pontos de lógica que não me parecem estar corretos.

Começo por indicar que tem vários pequenos erros de ortografia que deve corrigir para que o código fique o mais legível possível.

Exemplos retirados do código:

- `anxexarColuna`
- `linnha`

Passando agora para a implementação das funções de anexar.

**Anexar Linha**

A `MATRIZ` guarda um array de linhas (no campo `A`), logo acrescentar uma linha é aumentar este array.

Isto torna esta função de anexar linha a mais fácil pois necessita apenas de uma realocação da matriz de linhas com a função [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) e de aumentar o valor das linhas na estrutura:

```
void anexarLinha(MATRIZ* m){
    m->A = realloc(m->A, (++m->linhas*sizeof(PONT)));
}
```

O `realloc` funciona em tudo semelhante ao `malloc` e temos garantia, que o conteúdo do array é preservado mesmo que seja reposicionado em memoria.

**Anexar Coluna**

A lógica por detrás da implementação deste é diferente pois não existe um array de colunas. As colunas são cada um dos nós das linhas, logo realocar o array não fará sentido.

Em vez disso devemos percorrer cada linha e adicionar um novo nó no fim de cada uma, o que por si irá representar uma nova coluna.

```
void anexarColuna(MATRIZ* m){

    int linha;
    //percorrer todas as linhas para que crie um novo nó em cada
    for (linha = 0; linha < m->linhas ; linha++){

        //criar o novo nó da linha que representa a nova coluna
        PONT novo = malloc (sizeof(NO)); 
        novo->valor = 0;
        novo->prox = NULL;

        if (m->A[linha] == NULL){ //se a linha não tem nada atribui diretamente no array
            novo->coluna = 0; //coluna 0 pois é o primeiro nó da linha
            m->A[linha] = novo;
        }
        else { //a linha já tem nós por isso adiciona ao fim
            PONT atual = m->A[linha];

            while(atual->prox != NULL){
                atual=atual->prox;
            }

            novo->coluna = atual->coluna + 1; //atribuir a coluna correta ao nó
            atual->prox = novo;
        }
    }

    m->colunas++; //aumentar o tamanho das colunas na MATRIZ
}
```

[Exemplo a funcionar com estas funções de anexar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/4gSUGt)

Comment: Você solucionou meu problema, agradeço muito por tudo.

Comment: @AlexCosta De nada. Qualquer questão é só colocar. Resto de bom desenvolvimento para si.